# Hello, Can anyone show me an example (code) of a Remote Call Back in RMI ? Is their standard code for this process?

Tags: rmi, rpc, distributed-computing

Is it just for some revisions I'm doing on RMI? Been just researching and finding it difficult to find an example of "a remote call back".

OK, I shall add to this, is the following a good way to describe an example of a callback?

> "You have a Server and a Client. Server calls method from Client,
>   Client has already looked up Server and passed reference to itself."

How's that? Is it better?

Thanks,

Caroline

Comment: Please take a look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: it's OK I've found my example. But I think to ask for an example of a remote callback in rmi is as clear as it gets :-) or maybe I missed one word out, describe an example..... slappa my thighs.

Comment: Ok ok I've edited my question. I think I may very well have answered my own question ? Not sure....

Answer (score 1):

> is this a good way to describe an example of a callback ?
>
> "You have a Server and a Client. Server calls method from Client, Client has already looked up Server and passed reference".

Yes. You've omitted that the client object must be an exported remote object, typically by extending `UnicastRemoteObject,` and must implement a remote interface. Just like the server.